# Option Menu Not Displaying Text

Tags: android

I created my menu with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/donate" 
        android:icon="@drawable/donate" 
        android:title="Donate"/>

    <item android:title="@string/color_picker" 
        android:id="@+id/color_picker" 
        android:icon="@drawable/colorpicker"/>
</menu>
```

When I hit the menu button the images appear but the text does not.
I'm trying to get the text to show and as far as I can tell the text should appear... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are u able to display text+image on menu item ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, I think that your icons are not the right size.
I had the same problem and fixed it with appropriate icon sizes.
Check out this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets

Basically you have to create 3 sets of the same icons but with different sizes:

`/res/drawable-hdpi` with 72 by 72 pixel icons

`/res/drawable-mdpi` with 48 by 48 pixel icons

and

`/res/drawable-ldpi` with 36 by 36 pixel icons

So when your app is run on a HTC Wildfire for example, `@drawable/donate` will actually refer to `/res/drawable-ldpi/donate.png` 
but on a MyTouch3G it will refer to `/res/drawable-mdpi/donate.png`

Comment: It is like this... I made a test project with the same setup without the actual apps functionality but it does display the icon. I'm very confused

Comment: @Mircrea Nistor if you explanation was correct then we should be able to display Text+app_icon(provided by android at the time of project creation for all 3 layouts) in menu item. But, i was not able to display text and image on the menu item. So, is there any way where i can display Text+Image on menu item

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the icons are visible this means your menu code is OK. Just an idea - try the `android:titleCondensed` attr. The doc says:

> String resource. A condensed title as
>   a string resource or a raw string.
>   This title is used for situations in
>   which the normal title is too long.

Maybe this is just your case?

Comment: Hm.. then just don't know what to propose. Crazy guess - is it possible the colors of the text and the background are the same?

Comment: I would think so i need to check the .png but i think it has a transparent bg

Answer (score 0):

do your menu.xml contain complete menu section?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/buyCoke"
    android:title="Buy Coke" 
    android:icon="@drawable/coke"/> </menu>
```

Comment: Yes it does. If I take the drawable out it the text does show but obviously no icon shows. Could i have a messed up .png thats causing the text to not show?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of the style used in your layout.

Define a new style and use it in your layout to solve this.

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">#fff</item>  // background color of the menus
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>  // text color of the menus
</style>
```

Use it like this in your layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
    android:background="@color/primary_pink"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```